# Issue in consuming webservice from angular2 service

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I tried to create a service which would read the data from the .json file and render a method with the json data which would be invoked by the angular2 components. (Ideally in the realtime appliation the service would consume the WebAPI service and return the data to the angular2 components)
The JSon data read from the service would be rendered in the form of BubbleChart which the bubblechartcomponent takes care of it. I was able to render the bubblechart without consuming the service, but after introducing the angular2 service components it stopped working. Can anyone help me with identifying the issue and resolve this issue?

Please find the plunker which simulates the actual application 
https://plnkr.co/edit/9RjP4rpY4d7EnA4Z5sRQ?p=preview

The code for Dataservice is below

```
    import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, Headers, Response, JSONP_PROVIDERS, Jsonp } from 'angular2/http';
import { Configuration } from './Configuration';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

///Service class to call REST API
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    private DataServerActionUrl: string;
    private headers: Headers;
    result: Object;

    constructor(private _http: Http) {
        console.log("constructor of DataService with Http Injectable");
        //this.DataServerActionUrl = "http://localhost:23647/api/extractorqueue/getextractorqueueslatest/"; 
        this.DataServerActionUrl = "Bubblechartdata.json":
    }

    public GetExtractorQueuesLatest = (): Observable<Response> => {
        console.log("Inside method GetExtractorQueuesLatest");
        console.log("API URL: " + this.DataServerActionUrl);

         return this._http.get(this.DataServerActionUrl)
            .map(Response => Response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: any) {
        console.log("in Error");
        let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
            error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
        console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
}
```

My Main.ts file looks like below

```
//main entry point
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, Headers, Response, JSONP_PROVIDERS, Jsonp } from 'angular2/http';
import {DataService} from './DataService';
import {BubbleChartComponent} from './BubbleChartComponent';

bootstrap(BubbleChartComponent, [DataService, HTTP_PROVIDERS])
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

My bubblechartcomponent looks like below

```
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, Headers, Response, JSONP_PROVIDERS, Jsonp } from 'angular2/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from 'angular2/core';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/common';
import { DataService } from '../DataService';
declare var d3: any;

@Component({
    styles: [``],
    directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [DataService, HTTP_PROVIDERS],
    templateUrl: 'bubblechart.html'
})

export class BubbleChartComponent implements OnInit {
    public resultData: any;

    constructor(private _dataService: DataService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._dataService.GetExtractorQueuesLatest()
            .subscribe(
            (res) => {
                this.resultData = res;
                this.DrawBubbleChart();
            },
            (error) => console.log(error),
            () => console.log('Extractor Queues Latest')
            );
    }

    margin = 25;
    diameter = 915;
    color = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([-1, 5])
        .range(["hsl(152,80%,80%)", "hsl(228,30%,40%)"])
        .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

    pack = d3.layout.pack()
        .padding(2)
        .size([this.diameter - this.margin, this.diameter - this.margin])
        .value(function (d) { return d.size; })

    svg = d3.select("router-outlet").append("svg")
        .attr("width", this.diameter)
        .attr("height", this.diameter)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.diameter / 2 + "," + this.diameter / 2 + ")");

    private DrawBubbleChart(): void {

        var chart = d3.json(this.resultData, (error, root) => {
            if (error) throw error;

            var focus = root,
                nodes = this.pack.nodes(root),
                view;

            var circle = this.svg.selectAll("circle")
                .data(nodes)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("class", function (d) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
                .style("fill", (d) => { return d.children ? this.color(d.depth) : null; })
                .on("click", (d) => { if (focus !== d) zoom.call(this, d), d3.event.stopPropagation(); });

            var text = this.svg.selectAll("text")
                .data(nodes)
                .enter().append("text")
                .attr("class", "label")
                .style("fill-opacity", function (d) { return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0; })
                .style("display", function (d) { return d.parent === root ? "inline" : "none"; })
                .text(function (d) { return d.name; });

            var node = this.svg.selectAll("circle,text");

            d3.select("router-outlet")
                .style("background", this.color(-1))
                .on("click", () => { zoom.call(this, root); });

            zoomTo.call(this, [root.x, root.y, root.r * 2 + this.margin]);

            function zoom(d) {
                var focus0 = focus; focus = d;

                var transition = d3.transition()
                    .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750)
                    .tween("zoom", (d) => {
                        var i = d3.interpolateZoom(view, [focus.x, focus.y, focus.r * 2 + this.margin]);
                        return (t) => { zoomTo.call(this, i(t)); };
                    });

                transition.selectAll("text")
                    .filter(function (d) { return d.parent === focus || this.style.display === "inline"; })
                    .style("fill-opacity", function (d) { return d.parent === focus ? 1 : 0; })
                    .each("start", function (d) { if (d.parent === focus) this.style.display = "inline"; })
                    .each("end", function (d) { if (d.parent !== focus) this.style.display = "none"; });
            }

            function zoomTo(v) {
                var k = this.diameter / v[2]; view = v;
                node.attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + (d.x - v[0]) * k + "," + (d.y - v[1]) * k + ")"; });
                circle.attr("r", function (d) { return d.r * k; });
            }
        });
    }

}
```

the following references are added in the Index.html file

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.35.0/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.26/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/angular2@2.0.0-beta.16/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.16/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.26/system.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/typescript@1.8.10/lib/typescript.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.16/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.16/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
```

Not sure how do I add the following line in the plunker, but in my local version of the code i have included it in my Index.html file

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
```

what else I am missing and to make it work? please help

Comment: You have too many errors in plunker - using different versions of angular, bad urls for scripts, you didn't import stuff before using it... Try to clean up a code until you get the actual app error.

Comment: The bubblecomponent is also missing a selector.. in bootstrap you tried to inject the service without importing ```import {DataService} from './DataService'``` it first

Comment: I did all the changes from the comments, still facing issue in loading the component and bubblechart. can anyone please help me on this issue? I am struck with this issue..

Comment: @Krishnan you still have errors, in *index.html* use `System.import('app')` instead and in *src/BubbleChartComponent.ts* it should be `import { DataService } from './DataService';` After that you will see there is an error with your data service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of errors that you need to correct

### index.html

Your importing the bootstrap incorrectly on ln#23 instead of *main* it should be *app*

`System.import('app')`

### src/DataService.ts

You are missing the import for rxjs catch operator
`import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';`

### src/BubbleChartComponent.ts

you import path for DataService is correct it should be
`import { DataService } from './DataService';`

## app problem

once you fix those, you'll see a request to `https://run.plnkr.co/LOM2gOWjWHv4fTSE/[object%20Object]` with 404. Inspection of stack shows its originating from BubbleChartComponent.DrawBubbleChart.

I'm not really familiar with d3 but I'm guessing that you are an incorrect function to import the data. You are using
`var chart = d3.json(this.resultData, (error, root) => {` on ln#52, from a quick google this expects a path to a json file, however `this.resultData` is an object.